# Exportar página web a PDF usando html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Hay forma de poder exportar mi pdf con html2pdf sin que afecte mi tabla que está de forma vertical?

Tengo 2 tablas así, y ambas salen como la siguiente imagen:

TABLA ORIGINAL
[image: TABLA ORIGINAL]

SALIDA DE IMAGEN PDF
[image: SALIDA DE IMAGEN PDF]

Este es mi css con el que cambio la forma de mi tabla:

```
.tabla-vertical td {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Este es mi script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const $boton = document.querySelector("#btnCrearPdf");
  $boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const $elementoParaConvertir = document.body;
    html2pdf()
    .set({
      margin: .1,
      filename: 'documento.pdf',
      image: {
        type: 'jpeg',
        quality: 0.98
      },
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 2,
        letterRendering: true,
      },
      jsPDF: {
        unit: "cm",
        format: [50, 165],
        orientation: 'portrait'
      }
    })
    .from($elementoParaConvertir)
    .save()
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
});
```